# A more succint way to use ReaderWriterLockSlim in many properties

Tags: c#, thread-safety, dry, readwritelock

I am trying to implement many properties that utilize ReaderWriterLockSlim for thread safety.
So like most I end up with something like this in all my properties:

```
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        rwLock.EnterReadLock();
        try {
            return name;
        }
        finally {
            rwLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }
    set
    {
        rwLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try {
            name = value;                    
        }
        finally {
            rwLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

This feels very verbose and repetitive in 10 properties, so I am looking for a more DRY implementation.

The obvious solution is to wrap it into a class which releases the lock on dispose and allows me to put my thread safe operations within a using statement. Apparently this isn't very safe according to [this](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=21) and a few other sources.

So I have tried to come up with a nice looking solution using lambda expressions and anonymous methods:

```
private TResult ThreadSafeRead<TResult>(Func<TResult> value)
{
    rwLock.EnterReadLock();
    try {
        return value();
    }
    finally {
        rwLock.ExitReadLock();
    }            
}

private void ThreadSafeWrite(Action value)
{
    rwLock.EnterWriteLock();
    try {
        value();
    }
    finally {
        rwLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}

public string Name
{
    get { return ThreadSafeRead(() => name); }
    set { ThreadSafeWrite(() => { name = value; }); }
}
```

While this eliminates the repetitive code that was annoying me, I have no idea if it is as thread safe as my original verbose implementation.

Does anyone with a greater understanding of the MSIL this will generate and multi-threading
theory be able to tell me if my implementation is safe?

Comment: This has nothing to do with thread-safety. The problem comes from calling Thread.Abort on your thread.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way I've seen people go about this is by wrapping the lock in an object and doing something along the lines of:

```
using (var obj = new ReadOnlyLock(this.rwLock))
{
    this.name = value;
}
```

I will admit I don't do this (why create another object just to take a lock?) but it does achieve the better style goal that some see as paramount...

Comment: As I mentioned, a using statement wrapping the lock is the obvious solution, but I have found numerous sources explaining that it is not thread safe. See [here](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=21).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply it is perfect. I don't use it. Rather, I'm just saying it is a *common* pattern used to solve your problem.
I will admit, I don't think this is a problem really worth solving...

Comment: @KrisG: Nonsense, why wouldn't that be thread-safe? (The article you linked to describes a general problem with try-finally...)

Comment: It is a solution, but it is less safe than using try finally manually, because the creation of the IDisposable could fail *after* acquiring the lock. In this case the lock would not be released.

Answer (score -1):

The problem mentioned in your blog post does exist, yes. For a more thorough treatment of this subject see [Joe Duffy's post](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=c1898a31-a0aa-40af-871c-7847d98f1641).

Does your code even suffer from asynchronous exceptions? In all likelihood they only happen when running under ASP.NET and the current request gets aborted due to a timeout. Of course, you should never abort a thread yourself for various reasons.

I don't think you should be practically concerned with this problem.